# Using given with parametrize

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I was wondering if it is possible to use `given` with parameters comes from pytest's `parametrize` function.
Example:

```py
import pytest
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@st.composite
def my_strategy(draw, attribute):
    # Body of my strategy
    return # Something...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("attribute", [1, 2, 3])
@given(my_strategy(attribute))
def test_foo(strategy):
    pass
```

On `@given(my_strategy(attribute))` I want that `attribute` will be parametrize's attribute and generate new `my_strategy` every run with the wanted `attribute`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one possible workaround I can think of is to construct strategy inside the test and use [`data` strategy](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#interactive-draw) to draw examples, something like

```py
import pytest
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@st.composite
def my_strategy(draw, attribute):
    # Body of my strategy
    return # Something...

@given(data=st.data())
@pytest.mark.parametrize("attribute", [1, 2, 3])
def test_foo(attribute, data):
    strategy = my_strategy(attribute)

    example = data.draw(strategy)
    ...  # rest of the test
```

But I think the best way will be to write strategy without mixing it with `mark.parametrize`:

```py
@given(st.sampled_from([1, 2, 3]).flatmap(my_strategy))
def test_foo(example):
    ...  # rest of the test
```

Comment: Correct on both counts - it's generally nicer to stick to Hypothesis if you can, but if not using the data() strategy to draw inside your test function is the only option (and while inelegant it works very well).